# Why no more "python-support" in 16.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I'm curious why the python-support package [no longer exists](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/python-support) in 16.04 - is this related to changing Python3 to be the default? Furthermore, is there any package that "requires" it that actually doesn't install and run ok by [forcing the dependencies](http://tunesviewer.sourceforge.net/installing-tunesviewer-in-ubuntu-16-04/)?

Is there any danger in package maintainers just removing "python-support" from the requirements list, to fix this issue in an update?

Comment: It worked for gnome-scheduler, I just had to change python-support to dh-python in Control. In the Rules, I had to change dh_pysupport to dh_python2.

Answer (score 34):

Had the same issue when trying to install cassandra on 16.04. Solved it with:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/109052632/python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
```

Source: https://github.com/ajenti/ajenti/issues/903#issuecomment-215569332

Comment: Thanks so much you saved me from having to install Debian Jessie.

Comment: you saved my life ...

Comment: This solves issues with Folding@home (control and viewer) on 16.04 as well, thanks.  Could details be given about launchpadlibrarian.net, or do more generic solutions exist?

Comment: Probably not the greatest solution as you are supposed to use dh-python now: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=787040

Answer (score 1):

You linked to the source package, but the `python-support` package definitely does exist in the binary repositories:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/python-support

I'm not sure why it doesn't show up in the source repos -- maybe because it's just a Python script that can be executed directly, rather than something that requires compilation into a binary in order to be useful.

Does this answer your question, or do you require a package in the "source" repos?

Comment: No, they are deleted. From that page, click any architecture and note that the page says status: deleted. For example: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/python-support/1.0.15

Comment: So does `sudo apt-get install python-support` actually install something on your system?

Comment: @NoBugs You're correct -- I shouldn't have been so hasty to say what I said.  According to one answer on this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-support/+bug/1577172 , *"python-support was removed from Debian and later from Ubuntu. Please use dh_python2 from dh-python package instead."*

Comment: So should packagers include both: ` python-support | dh-python ` in depends field? This would suggest that would work: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough to know the answer to that (I've never packaged anything!). But it does sound reasonable.